# Alternative to Sumproduct / Sumif / Sumifs

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking for an alternative solution to using Sumproduct / Sumif / Sumifs (basically, array formulas) when it comes to the example provided below. I have scoured Stackoverflow and I am coming up woefully empty. I am open to any-and-all suggestions to achieve better performance that do not involve changing out of Excel because that is the medium I have been ordered to do this in. Thank you in advanced for your time!

My problem is thus: I have an excel workbook that takes 40-90 seconds to calculate, depending on PC specs. I have narrowed the calculation problems to a series of array calculations. When these array calculations are removed, my workbook takes 3 seconds to fully re-calculate... so yes I am sure these are the bottleneck.

My array calculations are like so: I have a list of zone names (eg: North America, Western Europe, etc...) on Sheet 1, row 2, extending to column HJ. I have a list of values on Sheet 2 rows 2-500, also extending to column HJ. I need to aggregate/"sum-up" all of the values on Sheet 2, based on the zone names on Sheet 1. The columns are in a direct 1-to-1 relationship, so the following formulae all work and create the exact same values:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(Sheet2!A2:Sheet2!HJ2, --(Sheet1!$A$2:Sheet1!$HJ$2 = "North America"))
=SUMIF(Sheet1!$A$2:Sheet1!$HJ$2, "North America", Sheet2!$A2:Sheet2!$HJ2) 
=SUMIFS(Sheet2!$A2:Sheet2!$HJ2, Sheet1!$A$2:Sheet1!$HJ$2, "North America")
```

The performance of doing these array calculations is "unacceptable" to the powers that be. I am fairly certain that my response should be "tough noogies", but I must do my due diligence on finding an alternative.

So am I doing anything wrong with these array calculations? Can I restructure them somehow? I am fine with helper rows, UDF's, etc...

Thanks again!

Comment: Could you use a pivot table? These are much faster....Alternatively, you could save the file without the formulas (once a day depending on how often the users need refreshes) so that when they open the file, it's not calculating anymore, then just calculate in one main workbook to distribute each day.

Comment: Each of the formulas you posted is incredibly efficient and quick to calculate. What's more, the ranges they are referencing are not particularly large at all. Precisely how many copies of these formulas do you have at any given time in your workbook?

Comment: How many of these formulas do you have? One for each pair consisting of a zone name and a row in the range 2 to 500? If all of these formulas are in a single block of cells, perhaps you can have a single UDF array function for the results.

Comment: OpiesDad: I will look into a pivot table, thank you for the suggestion. As for tricks with saving, the workbook will be out of my hands and distributed when complete so I am unable to do such activities.

XOR LX and John Coleman: You have both hit on the reason for why I am asking stackoverflow. I have read about people not complaining until having tens of thousands of array formuals; so my issue seemed odd in comparison. I have 500 rows, aggregating into 9 distinct columns, therefore 4,500 SUM formulas. Each of these traverse two arrays of 218 cells each. Is that alot?

Comment: I honestly cannot believe that those formulas alone would take more than a second or two to calculate. Are the formulas you posted precisely those you are using? You're not, for example, using SUMPRODUCT with a much larger range being referenced than that you posted here?

Comment: 4500 array formulas each of which traverse 2x218 cells doesn't seem like a lot. Certainly nothing that would explain 40-90 seconds of recalculation. Sounds like they might be depending on some volatile values

Comment: Agree with @JohnColeman, do you have a `Volatile` function somewhere else in the spreadsheet?  Typical offenders are `OFFSET` and `INDIRECT` or a UDF with `Application.Volatile = True`.  These volatile functions will cause a recalculation on every update and can create a cascade of updates.  http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsi.htm

Comment: I just performed a quick test in a new workbook in which I took the formula =SUMIF(Sheet1!$A$2:Sheet1!$HJ$2, "North America", Sheet2!$A2:Sheet2!$HJ2) and pasted it into 4500 rows beginning in Sheet1 row 3. I then placed the formula =IF(RANDBETWEEN(1,2)=1,"North America","") into Sheet1 B2:HI2 and the formula =RANDBETWEEN(1,99) into the range Sheet2 A2:HJ4500. Full workbook recalculation takes less than half a second. And RANDBETWEEN is a volatile function. Are you sure there's not something else you're not telling us about your workbook?

Comment: The workbook as a whole is an amalgamation of formulas and logic spread across multiple sheets. The vast majority of these are simple calculations, none of which are volatile to my knowledge. One thing I did not include about the workbook is that those 500 rows, 218 columns of Sheet 2 values are references to "Total" values elsewhere in the workbook. I guess Excel must be coming up with some hefty dependency trees or something, because now that I test it, if I copy/paste the Sheet 2 as values (rather than them being references), the worksheet calculates speedily.

Comment: Would you be willing to share the workbook (desensitized if necessary)?

Comment: Thank you for your time spent and advice everyone (extra kudos to XOR LX). Unfortunately it would be quite the effort to try and desensitize and maintain a working workbook. This has helped though with my due diligence and I have plenty of ammo for showing the powers that be that we are in a "tough noogies" scenario. Thanks again!

Comment: Maybe try to save the spreadsheet as `.xlsb` format to see if that will help...